# Where to get detailed 3D world maps?

Tags: maps, gis, mapping

We're looking for detailed, accurate 3D maps such as the one pictured from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uQxraiCRK68&t=79s). Screenshot for reference:

[image]

I've looked at the following so far, but couldn't find anything that fits what we need:

- Google Earth - Deprecated APIs
- Bing Maps - Don't see any 3D maps available on their dev docs
- ArcGIS - Nothing as detailed as this
- TomTom - No 3D maps
- Cesium OSM Buildings - low poly buildings

We're happy to pay a premium for this service.

Where we can get this sort of data?

We need a web version, and preferably also a mobile SDK.